# View PDF or MS Office documents inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, excel, iframe, doc

I am trying to display different kinds of files inside a iframe. It works for text, images and pdf files but not working with MS office or Open office documents. Is there a way to do this? Also, it automatically starts to download files that cannot be opened, is there a way to stop this automatic download from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft now provides a nice web viewer, [explained here](https://products.office.com/en-US/office-online/view-office-documents-online)

It only works on files that are publicly available at some http endpoint, but thankfully, they do let you stick it an the iframe. Just append your filename as the src of this link:

`view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=`

A more interesting solution to me is to look around for ways to use open office on the command line. It has a capability to convert microsoft documents into open office format, at which point you can use the open source http://viewerjs.org/ and host it yourself if that's your style.

Comment: This didn't work for me with the file in Azure Blob Storage in a public container.  This also didn't work with a private file with the correct secure access signature.  The google viewer below worked like a charm.  as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `src` attribute in your `IFrame` refer to a direct link for the PDF, such as
`https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url={DirectPdfUrl}`, where `DirectPdfUrl` is a direct link to the PDF file (must be accessible over the internet, not locally!)